# Отправка почты java

Tags: java, email

Я хочу отправить почту на другой емайл через gmail в моем приложение java
я использую такие настройки

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username={my.email@tyt.by}
spring.mail.password={сгенерированный код с паролей приложений }
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true


   @Service
public class EmailServiceSender {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void sendSimpleEmail(String toEmail,
                                String subject,
                                String body
    ) {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("my.email@tut.by");
        message.setTo(toEmail);
        message.setText(body);
        message.setSubject(subject);
        mailSender.send(message);
        System.out.println("Mail Send...");


    }
@SpringBootApplication
public class Springsecurity61Application {
    @Autowired
    private EmailServiceSender senderService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Springsecurity61Application.class, args);
    }
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void triggerMail() throws MessagingException {
        senderService.sendSimpleEmail("kza91918@omeie.com",
                "This is email body",
                "This is email subject");

    }
```

Я получаю такую ошибку

```
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:440) ~[spring-context-support-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:323) ~[spring-context-support-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:312) ~[spring-context-support-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at com.example.springsecurity61.EmailServiceSender.sendSimpleEmail(EmailServiceSender.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.springsecurity61.Springsecurity61Application.triggerMail(Springsecurity61Application.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:348) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:233) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:370) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.ready(EventPublishingRunListener.java:109) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$ready$6(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:80) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.ready(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:80) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:331) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.example.springsecurity61.Springsecurity61Application.main(Springsecurity61Application.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l27-20020ac2555b000000b004fe1a35fd15sm226030lfk.140 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:979) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:890) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:794) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342) ~[jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:518) ~[spring-context-support-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:437) ~[spring-context-support-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Как мне исправить, что бы все работало корректно?

Comment: Ошибка сообщает, что у вас неверные логин/пароль к почтовому серверу.

Answer (score 0):

Я переделал все под яндекс

```
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.host=smtp.yandex.ru
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username={my.email}
spring.mail.password={my.code}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

поставил все галочки в Все настройки-Почтовые программы
И все заработало, письмо пришло.